# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. - NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a NodeJS Rest API where I have a user collection, besides that I do user SMS verification.

This is the controller for the POST `/:id/verification`

```
exports.verification = (req, res) => {

  const id = req.params.id

  return User.find(id)
    .then( user => {

      if (user.code !== req.body.code) {

        res.json({ message: 'Incorrect code' })

        res.sendStatus(500)

        return

      }

      user.isVerified = true

      user.save( error => {

        if (error) {

          res.json({ message: 'Failed to update user' })

          res.sendStatus(500)

          return

        }

        res.json({ user })

        res.sendStatus(200)

      } )

    } )
    .catch( error => {

      res.json({ error })

    } )

}
```

But the thing is that when I post to `/:id/verification` I get this error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. - NodeJS and Express

On this line:

```
res.json({ user })
res.sendStatus(200)
```

But I dont understand why, I dont send any response before this.

Can someone explain me what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using both `res.json()` and `res.sendStatus()` both together, both of them send `response` back, That is why it is showing error that `Can't set headers after they are sent`.

you should use only one of them.

If you want to send status along with the JSON response, you can try this:

```
res.status(500).json({ message: 'Incorrect code' });
```

Also, status of `200` is `default` when using `res.send`, `res.json`, etc. So you dont need to send `status 200` with `res.json()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ravi!

Answer (score 1):

res.json() send object to the clilent and after that you are trying to set the header with status code. So, it shows the error message. Use following code for set status and sending the content in the same time.

```
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' } /* json object*/);
```